# What is the ABSOLOUTE shortest way to write this code?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

So I got kinda bored and was wondering if it was possible to make this code shorter without modifying anything except a file named coin.py...

```
from random import*;c=['heads','tails'];print('u win'if choice(c)==input(' / '.join(c)+': ')else'u lose')
```

The program asks the user for either "heads" or "tails", if the result from `random.choice(c)` matches the user's input, print "you win" to the console. Otherwise print "you lose" to the console.

Example:

```
heads / tails: tails
u win


heads / tails: tails
u lose
```

(no loop needed btw, just run once)

Maintaining all its functionality & having the EXACT same output

Have fun, stack exchage :)

Update: Security practices don't matter for this question

Comment: Please take a look at [On "golf this for me" tips questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18610/on-golf-this-for-me-tips-questions). Your question should at minimum explain exactly what is the functionality that our further-golfed code should reproduce.

Comment: While your code decides the "correct" guess of heads and tails before you guess, there's no [observable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/20260) way to tell this from it just ignoring your guess and randomly saying you were right or wrong. Is it OK to shorten the code this way?

Comment: Is it necessary to handle when the input is neither `heads` nor `tails`?

Comment: Also, welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: @xnor: Probabilistically you could detect randomly saying right or wrong if the user repeatedly enters something that is *neither* `head` nor `tails` many times; if they enter `edge` every time, the current code will always say they lose, while just randomly picking the winner would tell them they won ~50% of the time.

Comment: Try posting this on code review

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian i was redirected here from stack overflow because around 10 people told me this was where I was supposed to post questions like this

Comment: @Eric [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: a semicolon is the same number of bytes as a newilne.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right, I was assuming the user could only enter `heads` or `tails`.

Comment: absoloute? :p this is some special difficulty :D

Comment: I feel like this was reopened without any of the reasons for closing being addressed.

Comment: @xnor my question was closed for being unclear. You know how to code. You understand the code. So where is the issue there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few improvements off the top of my head:

1. (Shaves two characters) You don't need a `list`, a `tuple` will do, so:

   ```
   c=['heads','tails']
   ```

   can shorten to (parentheses around `tuple`s are optional when it has at least one item and it's unambiguous):

   ```
   c='heads','tails'
   ```
2. (Shaves four characters) You can interleave the two output strings into a single one, and do a slice skipping by 2, with the start point based on your condition, shaving:

   ```
   print('u win'if choice(c)==input(' / '.join(c)+': ')else'u lose')
   ```

   down to:

   ```
   print('uu  lwoisne'[choice(c)==input(' / '.join(c)+': ')::2])
   # Or if you prefer, no change in length:
   print('u','lwoisne'[choice(c)==input(' / '.join(c)+': ')::2])
   ```
3. (Shaves five characters) Use `printf`-style formatting to construct your string, now that `c` is a `tuple`, this is cheap:

   ```
   print('uu  lwoisne'[choice(c)==input(' / '.join(c)+': ')::2])
   ```

   to:

   ```
   print('uu  lwoisne'[choice(c)==input('%s / %s: '%c)::2])
   ```

Comment: Instead of 3 you can do `'%s / %s: '%c`.

Comment: @loopywalt: Good point; forgot that the switch to `tuple` would enable that. Updated. The final line shaves the same number of characters either way, but it saves the four characters spent unpacking in the second line, so it's a much nicer win.

Comment: Amazing! This code is 94 characters long!